# Mysql .Net Select/Delete Auto Increment Value

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, vb.net, select

I have a mysql table call UIDhold and one column called `UID` (Primary key). I have values auto incrementing from 1-20000.

In my WPF app I have mysql .net  library reference and have successfully connected to the database. What I am I wondering is after connected to database, how would I select the UID (example; 1), store that value textbox or string variable`, then delete that UID from db table ?

When I execute in Mysql cmdline:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I get `0` ,but the 1st value should be `1`.

Any guidance would be great!

UPDATE:

I've figure out how to select the minium UID, which would be 1. However I do not know how to store it in a string variable/textbox. Syntax error at UIDTextBox.Text = myData. " Value of type System.data.datatable cannot be converted into string." So what do I need to do?

VB.Net

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data


Public Class test1


Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myData As New DataTable
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim connStr As String = "Database=;" & _
                       "Data Source=localhost;" & _
                       "User Id=;Password=;"
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)

    connection.Open()
    SQL = "SELECT MIN(UID) FROM `UIDhold`"


    myCommand.CommandText = SQL

    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
    myAdapter.Fill(myData)




    UIDTextBox.Text = myData

End Sub
End Class
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="test1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="test1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Sign In" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,159,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,38,0,0" Name="UIDTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" />
    <Label Content="UID" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,33,0,0" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Where in your code are you calling SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); you need to call it directly after the Insert. can you show the code that you are using to do the Insert..?

Comment: also to store the value in the Application level Properties.Settings you could look at this link for a great example [Saving to Properties.Settings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C)

Comment: I've figure out how to select the minium UID, which would be 1. However I do not know how to store it in a string variable/textbox. Syntax error at  UIDTextBox.Text = myData. " Value of type System.data.datatable cannot be converted into string." So what do I need to do? See VB code/XAML above.

Comment: I've found this example. However I want I don't want to use grid view seeing its a single number I am getting from my database. http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto incrementing can be done via the MySQL server itself. You just have to set that up when you set up your table.

```
CREATE TABLE data(
     UID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

So whenever you want to store it back into the database, if you set the value as null it will auto-increment.

```
INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
    ('ssss')
```

Also idk what you're trying to do (hopefully i understood it right); but, if you want to create the datatable, you would have to parse each row and then add it using a while loop i think.

```
    table.Columns.Add("UID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));


   using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTimeMySql(Locale.sqlDataConnectionDetailsMySQL))
    using (var sqlQuery = new MySqlCommand(preparedCommand, varConnection)) {
        using (var sqlQueryResult = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader())                 
                while (sqlQueryResult.Read()) {
//above is basic sql stuff i expect you know


//Here's where you ge thte data
                    int uid = sqlQueryResult["UID"] is int ? (int)sqlQueryResult["UID"] : 0;
                    string name = sqlQueryResult["name"].ToString();

// here is where you're outputting to your table
                    table.Rows.Add(uid,name); 
                }
         }
    }
```